# Decoding JSON when feed is inconsistent - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I don’t know how to handle a JSON feed in swift with the decodable protocol when the feed gives me two different results.  If there is more than one ‘entry’,  the json looks like this and the entry value is an array of objects

```
{
  "feed": {
    "publisher": "Penguin",
    "country": "ca"
  },
  "entry": [
    {
      "author": "Margaret Atwood",
      "nationality": "Canadian"
    },
    {
      "author": "Dan Brown",
      "nationality": "American"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if there is only a single entry, the json looks like this where entry is just a dictionary

```
{
  "feed": {
    "publisher": "Penguin",
    "country": "ca"
  },
  "entry": {
    "author": "Margaret Atwood",
    "nationality": "Canadian"
  }
}
```

to decode the first case, I would use the following structs

```
struct Book: Decodable {
    let feed: Feed
    let entry: [Entry]
}

// MARK: - Entry
struct Entry: Decodable {
    let author, nationality: String
}

// MARK: - Feed
struct Feed: Decodable {
    let publisher, country: String
}
```

And then use something like this to decode the data retrieved

```
 let  object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data)
```

How do I handle the case when the entry is not an **array** of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly override the decoder for Book. What you can do is to try to unwrap an [Entry]s and upon failing that, just try to unwrap a single Entry.

For example:

```
struct Book: Decodable {
   let feed: Feed
   let entry: [Entry] 
   init (from decoder :Decoder) throws {
     let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      do {
        value = try container.decode([Entry].self, forKey: .value)
      } catch {
        let newValue = try container.decode(Entry.self, forKey: .value)
        value = [newValue]
      }
   }
}
```

Note: that's not a comprehensive sample on what you want to do but just a way you can accomplish what you want to do

Comment: Your second `value =` will need an extra set of square brackets to make it an array as well: `value = [try container ...]`.

Comment: @RobNapier I wasn't trying to really give line by line code but the general idea (the compiler will complain with how it needs to complain) but I updated so it takes it into account.

Comment: I know, but that particular error will cause enough confusion that I expect readers will miss the value of the rest your answer (which is quite good).